# Navigate limitTo batches in Angular ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ngRepeat` with a `limitTo` in my HTML. This will show the first x number of users - essentially paginating the table. I now need to be able to show the next batch of x users. I've added a couple of anchors to go to previous or next page (with functions attached to the click) 
I'm now not sure how to manipulate the `ngRepeat` through these functions to actually show the correct batch of users.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | limitTo:paginate.size">
  {{user.name}}
  {{user.email}}
</div>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="" data-ng-click="prevPage()">left</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-ng-click="nextPage()">right</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.users = //full users object here

$scope.paginate = {};
$scope.paginate.size = 10;

$scope.prevPage = function(){
  //load the previous 10 users
}

$scope.nextPage = function(){
  //load the next 10 users
}
```

Comment: you dont need that much code. just `user in users.splice(page.start, page.end)`

Answer (score 0):

You should add another filter (or simply a custom filter) such as

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:getList(user, index)">
  {{user.name}}
  {{user.email}}
</div>
```

and then in the scope

```
$scope.users = //full users object here

$scope.paginate = {};
$scope.paginate.size = 10;
$scope.paginate.start = 0;

$scope.prevPage = function(){
  //load the previous 10 users
    if ($scope.paginate.start) {
        $scope.paginate.start -= $scope.paginate.size;
    }
}

$scope.nextPage = function(){
  //load the next 10 users
    $scope.paginate.start += $scope.paginate.size;
}

$scope.getList = function (user, index) {
    return (index >= $scope.paginate.start && index < $scope.paginate.start + $scope.paginate.size);
};
```

Comment: Keep getting the error here that it is expecting an array into the get list functions, any tips? ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? What "get list functions"?

Comment: Sorry was typing too fast in here is a function getList, last comment I said it as get list, this function for me keeps returning the error that it is expecting an array instead of an object.

Comment: but how can that function be doing that, it is listed in the source code above and as you can see, it is not doing anything with arrays. Can you create a JSFiddle?